# Mongodb doesn't not update when I use like this

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make short way for me. I want to create one function for all queries. For `settings.amount`, `settings.balance` etc..

```
exports.updateUsers = function ( user_id, where, what, pass )  {
    var _where = 'settings.'+where; //when I use it doesn't update
    user.findOneAndUpdate(
          {'user_id' : user_id}, 
          {_where : what }).exec(function(e,d){
            pass("ok")
          })
};
```

How can I achive my want? Are there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{_where : what }` treats `_where` as a `String` literal, which is equivalent to: `{"_where":what}`. Hence you don't get any updated results since there is no field such as `_where`. You need to assign it in the below way to get it working.

```
exports.updateUsers = function ( user_id, where, what, pass )  {
    var _where = 'settings.'+where; //when I use it doesn't update
    var update = {};
    update[_where] = what;
    user.findOneAndUpdate(
          {'user_id' : user_id}, 
          update).exec(function(e,d){
            pass("ok")
          })
};
```

`update[_where] = what;` resolves the value in the `_where` variable.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to mongo, and could you give an example of how to update using this function? Thanks! I mean what should I need to use for where, what, and pass? Also, there are 2 things going to update in function right(.exec(function(e,d))?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the $set operator. See [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) for examples.

So I think your functions could be written like this:

```
exports.updateUsers = function ( user_id, where, what, pass )  {
    var setQuery = { $set: {} };
    setQuery.$set['settings.'+where] = what;
    user.findOneAndUpdate(
          {'user_id' : user_id}, 
          setQuery).exec(function(e,d){
            pass("ok")
          })
};
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to mongo, and could you give an example of how to update using this function? Thanks! I mean what should I need to use for where, what, and pass? Also, there are 2 things going to update in function right(.exec(function(e,d))?