# Creating Functions in MongoDB Console

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

This query returns a result `db.graduates.find({student_id: '2010-01016'}).pretty()`

and then I built a function

```
function findStud(name,value){ return db.graduates.find({name:value}); }
```

on the mongo shell when I run this `findStud("student_id","2010-01016")`
it does not display the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compose an query object with the `key` being the value in the `name`parameter and `value` being the value in the parameter `value`.

```
function findStud(name,value){
var query = {};
query[name] = value;
return db.graduates.find(query); 
}
```

By default when you don't do this, `name` is considered to be a `String` literal and the query gets executed as `db.graduates.find({"name":value});` which searches for a key named `name` with the specified value, causing the query to fail.

See Also: [Mongodb doesn't not update when I use like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003540/mongodb-doesnt-not-update-when-i-use-like-this/27003896#27003896)